# SuperUser migrated question solution - Check HTTP Referrer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, migration

A lot of people have been complaining that they can't read their questions once it's migrated to SU and while I agree that **the password is no state secret** (it's stated in the blog), most people don't have the means of looking for the password (especially not the SU population). They see **private** and then just get frustrated and leave.

I think as a simple solution would be to verify if the HTTP Referrer (or Referer as misspelled in the standard) is an SO or SF question, then simply don't ask for the password. (And of course don't ask the password on subsequent visits)

Answer (score 3):

A simpler solution would be to end with SU beta period - which is already happening, making the problem go away entirely, at least for that site. Admittedly we get into the same situation for future sites, but I'm not sure how many of those we should expect (of the same kind, rather than StackExchange sites).

Answer (score 1):

Sort of irrelevant since the beta is ending Monday at 23:59..